# Reliable communication over two sockets

Tags: linux, networking

Let's say I have two Ethernet connections (on different interfaces) between two machines, and each of these connections are unidirectional (like two data diodes in opposing directions; not even ACK packets can go in the reverse direction).

Is there a reliable packet-based protocol (either transport-layer or lower, or application layer over e.g. UDP) that is implemented over two unidirectional sockets (one sending socket, one receiving socket)?

Alternatively, would there be a way to use `TUN/TAP` devices to simulate a bidirectional socket?

Comment: You know what they say... Those who do not use TCP are bound to reinvent it...

Comment: How does TCP handle any of the requirements listed above except reliability?